# Wick contraction for unperturbative fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, wick-theorem

Say I want to calculate the transition amplitude of a meson to 2 photons using QED only:
$$\langle \gamma(q1) \gamma(q2)|meson\rangle$$

I can start with normal perturbation theory:
$$\langle \gamma(q1) \gamma(q2)|T\{e^{-i\int{dx H_{I}}}\}|meson\rangle$$
and Taylor expand the time-ordered expenetial. Here we consider $H_I$ as $ej^{\mu}A_\mu$ where $j^{\mu}$ is the quark current $\bar{q} Q\gamma^{\mu} q$.

At second order in e: 
$$\langle \gamma(q1) \gamma(q2)|\frac{(-i)^2}{2}T\{\int dx j(x)^{\mu} A(x)_{\mu} \int dyj(y)^{\nu} A(y)_{\nu}\}|meson\rangle$$

Now we can do wick contraction, so basically the $A_{x}$ and $A_{y}$ will contract with the outgoing photons.

Then we are left with something proportional to:

$$\langle 0|T\{\int dx j(x)^{\mu}  \int dy j(y)^{\nu} \}|meson\rangle \epsilon(q1)_{\mu} \epsilon(q2)_{\nu}$$

These results are shown in eq.(3) of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.02881

I know it's impossible to do it perturbatively but how can we only use the interaction picture of photon fields in QED while we keep the currents to stay in the Heisenberg picture of QCD?

To do it rigorously I think one must express the currents to in the interaction picture of QED as well.

**Why can we Wick contract photon fields without contracting the currents?**

Comment: Are the currents here "external" or themselves expressions in the fields?

Comment: @ACuriousMind they are quark currents.